# Gradient of $a^\top \exp(Xb)$ with respect to $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis

Given $f=a^\top \exp(Xb)$, where $a$ is a is $m \times 1$ vector, $X$ is $m \times n$ matrix, and $b$ is $n \times 1$ vector. How to solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$?

Comment: How is the exponential of a vector defined?

Comment: I guess it should be element-wise exponential of the vector, which results in a $m \times 1$ vector.

Comment: In that case the derivative should be $a^\top b \exp(Xb)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But I guess $a^\top b$ may be incorrect since $a$ is $m \times 1$ vector and $b$ is $n \times 1$ vector? Or did I miss something? Could you please give more detailed analysis?

Comment: You can write the gradient quite succinctly as
$$\large{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = {\rm Diag}\!\left(e^{Xb}\right)ab^\top
}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a "brute force" approach, we could write out $f$ as a summation.
$$
f(X) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i \exp \left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} b_j\right).
$$
From there, the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_{ij}$ is given by
$$
\partial_{x_{ij}}f = a_i b_j \exp\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} b_j\right) = a_i b_j [\exp(Xb)]_i.
$$
With that, the [numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) matrix expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$ is the matrix whose entries are $M_{ij} = a_i b_j [\exp(Xb)]_i$. One expression for this matrix is given by
$$
M = (a \circ \exp(Xb))b^\top,
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the entrywise (i.e. the "Hadamard" or "Schur") product.

If you intend to use this derivative for gradient descent, then you are likely after the denominator layout format for this derivative, which is simply the transpose of the matrix $M$ given above. In this case, we can write the answer as
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = b (a \circ \exp(Xb))^\top.
$$

---

Here's an attempt at a "trace-based" approach. We can write $f$ as
$$
f(X) = \operatorname{tr}[a^\top\exp(Xb)].
$$
With that, we have
$$
df = \operatorname{tr}[a^\top d[\exp(Xb)]] = 
\operatorname{tr}[a^\top \mathrm{diag}(\exp(Xb))d[Xb]]
\\ = \operatorname{tr}[a^\top \mathrm{diag}(\exp(Xb))[dX]b]
\\ = \operatorname{tr}[\left(ba^\top \mathrm{diag}(\exp(Xb))\right)dX ]
$$
If we note that $a^\top \mathrm{diag}(\exp(Xb)) = [a \circ \exp(Xb)]^\top$, then we can see that the result obtained in this fashion matches what we got above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This helps me a lot. But I'm also wondering how to slove the problem using trace-based method. Could you please give me some advice on that? Actually I'm trying to write, like, $df=da^\top \exp(Xb)+a^\top d\exp(Xb)=a^\top d\exp(Xb)$. Then get equations like $tr(df)=\cdots$. But I'm not sure how to deal with $a^\top d\exp(Xb)$.

Comment: @senli See my latest edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want. But I'm still a little confused about the equation $d[\exp(Xb)]=\mathrm{diag}(\exp(Xb))d[Xb]$. I try to understand it in this way: Use $(Xb)$ as a whole. So $d[\exp(Xb)]=\frac{\partial \exp(Xb)}{\partial (Xb)}d[Xb]$. $\exp(Xb)$ is $m \times 1$ vector, and $Xb$ is also $m \times 1$ vector. So $\frac{\exp(Xb)}{\partial (Xb)}$ is $m \times m$ matrix, which is $\mathrm{diag}(\exp(Xb))$. Am I right about the understanding?

Comment: @senli Yes, you're correct. It might help to note that the fact that $\frac{\partial \exp(y)}{\partial y}$ is diagonal corresponds to the fact that the $i$th entry of $\exp(y)$ depends only on $y_i$.

Comment: OK. Thanks again. This really helps me a lot.

Comment: @senli Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you could "accept" my answer by clicking the checkmark ($\checkmark$) under the vote arrows on my post.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have clicked the checkmark. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, thanks!